# Error : No instance of constructor matches the argument list

Tags: c++

I'm making ascending sort code with reading input.txt file and saving out.txt file. I've already done that in c, but I want to use this in c++.
I'm a beginner of c++. Could someone help me? I Really want to solve this problem.

There are errors :

> No instance of constructor matches the argument list ( "std::basic_ifstream<_ELEM, _Treaits>::get [대상_Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]" )

"in C"

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void my_sort(int *number, int size);

void main(void)
{
    FILE* const pFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if(pFile == NULL)
    {
        cout << "CAN'T OPEN!" << endl;
        return;
    }

    char szBuf[256];
    szBuf[sizeof(szBuf) - 1] = 0;
    int iSize = 0;
    while(fgets(szBuf, sizeof(szBuf) - 1, pFile))
        ++iSize;

    int* const piNumber = new int[iSize];

    rewind(pFile);

    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(szBuf, sizeof(szBuf) - 1, pFile))
    {
        const int iNumber = atoi(szBuf);
        piNumber[i++] = iNumber;
    }
    fclose(pFile);
    my_sort(piNumber, iSize);

    for(int j = 0; j < iSize; j++)
    {
        cout << piNumber[j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    delete[] piNumber; 

} 


void my_sort(int* number, int size)
{
     int i = 0, j = 0, temp = 0;

     for(j = 0;j < size; j++)
     {
          for(i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
          {
               if(number[i] > number[i + 1])
               {
                    temp = number[i];
                    number[i] = number[i + 1];
                    number[i + 1] = temp;
               }
          }
     }
```

"c++ with ERROR IN 'input', 'output' "

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void mySort(int* InputArrayPointer, int InputArraySize);

void main(void)
{
    ifstream input;
    input.open("input.txt", "r"); // ERROR
    if (input.fail())
    {
        cout << "CAN'T OPEN!" << endl;
        return;
    }

    char arr[256];
    arr[sizeof(arr) - 1] = 0;
    int size = 0;
    while (input.get(arr, sizeof(arr) - 1, input)) //ERROR
    ++size;

    int* const pointer = new int[size];

    rewind(input); //ERROR

    int i = 0;
   while (input.get(arr, sizeof(arr) - 1, input)) //ERROR
    {
        const int number = atoi(arr);
        pointer[i++] = number;
    }
    input.close(); 
    mySort(pointer, size);

    output.open("output.txt", "w"); //ERROR
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        output << pointer[j] << endl;
    }
    delete[] pointer;
    output.close();     
    }

void mySort(int* InputArrayPointer, int InputArraySize)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, temp = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < InputArraySize; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < InputArraySize - 1; i++)
        {
            if (InputArrayPointer[i] > InputArrayPointer[i + 1])
            {
                temp = InputArrayPointer[i];
                InputArrayPointer[i] = InputArrayPointer[i + 1];
                InputArrayPointer[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR----->

> No instance of constructor matches the argument list ( "std::basic_ifstream<_ELEM, _Treaits>::get [대상_Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]" )

Comment: Please don't use `new`. `std::unique_ptr` should be the default for dynamic memory and `std::vector` the default for arrays.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit. You should not vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

The mode you pass to `input.open` is not a string, like in C - it's a trait. Instead of

```
input.open("input.txt", "r"); // ERROR
```

use

```
input.open("input.txt", ios_base::in); // ERROR
```

For the output file, use `ios_base::out` - you also need to declare the `output` variable, which you don't appear to be be doing anywhere. You're also attempting to use a few functions like `rewind` which are used on C `FILE`s, rather than C++ streams.

Comment: You don’t even need to specify the direction if you use `ifstream` and `ofstream`.